# Parcel.js HMR & Socket.IO conflict (new user connection)

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, parceljs

I have an express application running with parcel bundler. I have implemented Socket.IO to this application (server & client).

Because the Hot Module Replacement from Parcel.js is working with web sockets as well, every time a modification is done, Socket.IO connection event gets triggered.

Is there a way to use HMR and Socket.IO at the same time without having this new connection ? If not, is there a way to detect if it's the HMR socket or a "real user connection" ?

I have tried to change the HMR port from Parcel.js but it didn't work.

Here is my server configuration :

```
const path = require('path')
const http = require('http')
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

// PARCEL BUNDLER
const Bundler = require('parcel-bundler')

const bundler = new Bundler(
  path.join(__dirname, './src/app.js'), {
  outFile: 'bundle.min.js',
  publicUrl: './',
  watch: true,
})

app.use(bundler.middleware())

// EXPRESS SERVER
const server = http.createServer(app)

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './dist'), { dotfiles: 'allow' }));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './index.html'));
});

server.listen(8080)

// SOCKET.IO
const io = require('socket.io')(server)

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.broadcast.emit('info', 'new user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    socket.broadcast.emit('info', 'user has been disconnected');
  });
});
```

On the client side, I just print the broadcast output so here is what i get (new user connection every time I do a modification in my files and HMR is fired)

[screenshot of my local web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIOnF.png)